# When is an MSE not usable?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $p$, with $n$ known and $p \in [0,1]$ unknow.

Let $T_c =c X/n$ be an estimator for $p$, where $c>0$ is yet to be determined.

(i) For which value of c is $T_c$ unbiased?
(ii) Determine the mean square error of $T_c$
(iii) For which value of c is this estimator optimal? Is this optimal estimator usable in practice?
(iv) Determine the limit of optimal value for c as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Which estimator $t_c$ do you obtain?

(i) $$E T_c=E(\frac{cX}{n})= \frac{c}{n}E(X)=\frac{c}{n}pn=cp \Rightarrow ET_c=p \Rightarrow c=1$$

(ii)
$$... MSE= \frac{c^2p(1-p)}{n}+p^2(c-1)^2$$

(iii)
$$...c=\frac{pn}{np-p+1}$$

(But I don't know whether it is usable and why)

(iv)

$$ c \rightarrow 1$$

Which was the value at which $T_c$ is unbiased.

---

After finding all these results I still can not answer the second part of (iii). Namely, I can not explain why this is unusable. Can somebody help me understand?

Comment: Presumably (ii) is $E[(T_c-p)^2]$ calculated as a function of $p$ and $n$.  I would guess that (iii) is asking for the $c$ which minimises the answer for (ii)

Comment: how can I minimise it? I think I already found a formula for MSE

Comment: Your expression for MSE has a typo, it should be $\frac{c^2p(1-p)}{n} + p^2(c-1)^2$.

Comment: How do you minimize a function of $c$?

Comment: I think I have to find the minimum of the MSE function in regards to the variable c

Comment: (iii) has a problem "with $n$ known and $p \in [0,1]$ unknown"

Comment: Does that mean that the MSE function has to not contain p?